# How to disable some payments while shipment is checked Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I have a question how to disable payment option called: "przelewy24" while the "przesyłka pobraniowa" and "płatność przy odbiorze" is checked. (both are the shipment). My code looks like, but it doesn't work:

```
/**
 * Filter payment gateways
 */
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
    $chosen_shipping_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:3', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['cod'] );

    elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:5', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['bacs'] );

    elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:5', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['przelewy24'] );

    elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:4', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['cod'] );

    elseif ( in_array( 'local_pickup:6', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways['cod'] );

    endif;

    return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_custom_available_payment_gateways' );
```

Comment: What are the shipping method id(s) for "przesyłka pobraniowa" and "płatność przy odbiorze" *(meaning something like `flat_rate:5`)*? Also you have 2 times that line in your code: `elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:5', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :` and the first will take the hand on the other.

Comment: "przesylka pobraniowa" is flat_rate5 - this is why I want to disable two options on that shipment. The "platnosc przy odbiorze" is local_pickup:6. Can you help please? :)

Comment: Yes of course I can… It should be nice if you could clarify with words what you want to do precisely (using the shipping method IDs and the payment method ID as the names in Russian are not explicit and not useful for this code)

Comment: I really appreciate. I would like to make in option "cash on delivery" - (platność przu odbiorze) invisible "Przelewy_24" (polish payment system). I have used unset( $gateways[‚przelewy24_payment’] ); like in the documentation but it doesn't work. This is the website: www.dexxer.pl